# GuzzleHttp not working

Tags: php, html, wiki, guzzle

I am using this code but its returning nothing, please help!

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$response = $client->request('GET', $this->baseUrl . '/profiles/' . $options['steamid'] . '/inventory/json/' . $options['appid'] . '/' . $options['contextid'] );
```

Comment: You want call function from Client  Class ??/

Answer (score 0):

either you're missing lots of code in your question, or you're missing lots of necessary syntax from your code.

either way, it should look something like this:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;properly.

class DoSomething 
{
  $client = new Client;  // <---- instantiate the object

  $response = $client->request('GET', $this->baseUrl . '/profiles/' . $options['steamid'] . '/inventory/json/' . $options['appid'] . '/' . $options['contextid'] );
}
```

you have to instantiate the object before you call its methods.  `Use` just essentially includes the class definition file, it doesnt actually create an object for you.

The only type of method you can use straight without instantiating its class is a static method.

```
SomeClass::someMethod();
```

But you cant do that in this particular case.

resources:

[guzzle docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/)

Comment: off-topic : The keyword `use` can be used [without](http://www.darkbee.be/stack/namespace/index.php) auto-loading